# Generating custom PDFs for service orders

Tags: pdf, custom, developer, visualforce-template

This is a somewhat broad question so I'm looking for expert guidance more so than concrete steps to take.

I'm looking to create a service order PDF in Salesforce. The main content looks a lot like what you can produce with a quote template (product and pricing info) but I'm also required to provide:

1. a cover page
2. signature page
3. fields that contain order data (e.g. order number)

How can I achieve this customization? Is this a Visualforce task?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You need to create a Visualforce Page and make it as renderAd="PDF" in  tag.

You need to consider few CSS Tricks if required to render as PDF properly.

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_Professional_PDF_Documents_with_CSS_and_Visualforce

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Formating-VisualForce-Page-rendered-as-PDF-1327108686696&language=en_US

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply.  So before I dig in and spend a lot of time ramping up on this, you are definitely sure type of thing is possible?  Key elements being cover page + order data + product / quote line item data + signature page?  Sorry for my hesitance, I just came into this task completely cold (brand new salesforce user).  Your links are VERY helpful, and a great starting point, I'm just a little nervous about hitting a deadend somewhere down the line.

Comment: Yes. You can start developing the page. Below link has possible problems(considerations) that can happen. If none of them is bothering you, then you are good to start.    https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_considerations.htm

Answer (score 0):

We have recently been developing a similar thing and have been using Conga (http://www.congamerge.com/) to populate a base template with data from the system.  May be worth taking a look.  It is fairly simple to use and the generation of the PDF can be fully automated with the flow version.